# Parsing JSON using Klaxon with Anko's doAsync fails to execute

Tags: android, json, kotlin, anko, klaxon

I'm trying to parse an url containing JSON whenever I press a button :

> ```
>     button.setOnClickListener {
> doAsync{
>     val result = URL("http://date.jsontest.com/").readText()
>     val parser: Parser = Parser()
>     val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(result)
>     val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
>     val time = "Time : ${json.string("time")}"
> uiThread { textView.setText(time) }}}
> ```

But I'm getting an error :

> Error pruning approved print services.                                                     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot get spooler!

What is wrong ?

Comment: I think this error comes from [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/print/java/com/android/server/print/RemotePrintSpooler.java) class, and it has something in common with remote printing. So I believe that code you showed to us is not the one responsible for exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after rebooting my pc and creating a new emulated device